# Get distinct of minimum value

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have this table `test` in Hive.

```
+----------+-------+-------+
|   name   | price | notes |
+----------+-------+-------+
| product1 |   100 |       |
| product1 |   200 | note1 |
| product2 |    10 | note2 |
| product2 |     5 | note2 |
+----------+-------+-------+
```

and I expect to get this result (distinct of products with minimum price)

```
+----------+-------+-------+
|   name   | price | notes |
+----------+-------+-------+
| product1 |   100 |       |
| product2 |     5 | note2 |
+----------+-------+-------+
```

I can't use the following query because of different `notes` in `product1`.

```
SELECT name, MIN(price), notes
FROM test
GROUP BY name, notes;

+----------+-------+-------+
|   name   | price | notes |
+----------+-------+-------+
| product1 |   100 |       |
| product1 |   200 | note1 |
| product2 |     5 | note2 |
+----------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: If you had your products with their min prices, what defines the correct value to return for the note?  Remembering that the minimum price row might not be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `notes` in group by and try again:-

```
SELECT name, MIN(price), notes
FROM test
GROUP BY name
```

[Run Code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73cd5/1)

Comment: gonna group by notes too ?

Comment: this is not valid SQL.

Comment: I have no idea what that is, but if you attempt execute your query in a Hive shell, it will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT name, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY price DESC),',',1) AS min_price,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(notes ORDER BY price DESC),',',1) AS note_value
FROM test
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: The question doesn't have an `impala` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Hive with [windowing functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics).

**Query**:

```
select distinct name
  , min_price
  , notes
from (
  select *
    , min(price) over (partition by name) num_price
  from db.table ) x
where min_price = price
```

**Output**:

```
product1    100        
product2    5      note2
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be found using a subquery as well.

```
    hive> select A.name,A.price,B.notes from (select name,min(price) as price from products group by name) as A
inner join (select name,price,notes from products) as B 
on a.name = b.name and a.price = b.price;
```

The above query will give the output as:

```
product1        100
product2        5       note2
```

But, the suquery approach has 2 iterations over the same table and is not suggested for larger tables.

For larger tables,see [@GoBrewers14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33272979/4160889) answer:

```
hive> select name,price,notes from (select *, min(price)over(partition by name) as min_price from products) as a
    > where a.price = a.min_price;
```

Comment: I don't understand what additional information this is adding.  If you are going to implement a sub-optimal solution, there needs to be a trade off (such as the code is much shorter).  There is no good reason to ever solve this problem with a self-join (if you have access to windowing functions), regardless of table size.

Comment: I felt that the subquery approach will help new users understand what happens internally. The subquery A is what the window partition does. min(price) over(partition by name). Subquery B is the regular select *. Now, we combine them in the outer select query.

Comment: That is not at all what happens internally.  If it did, then both queries would have the exact same run time.  [Here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/ptf/WindowingTableFunction.java) is what happens.